# Can't get original message in telegram bot response

Tags: api, bots, telegram-bot

So when a user sends a message to my bot, I send a message back asking for more information and set the reply_to_message field to the original message by the user (as described in the Telegram BOT API)

Once the user then replies back to my question, I try to check for the reply_to_messsage to extract the original message but it doesn't exist.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is the [ForceReply](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#forcereply).

If you use that, you can find your original message in the `reply_to_message`

Answer (score 0):

$message_reply=$update->message->reply_to_message; // if(message_reply) == true
$message_reply_message_text=$update->message->reply_to_message->text;
$message_reply_message_caption=$update->message->reply_to_message->caption; // text for picture